# Jquery and frames

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, frames

I am currently working on a web application that has been created using a magnitude of frames that stretch down up to 5 times, The issue is that i need to preform some jquery magic throughout the website.

What would be the best way to go about this (other than rewriting it which i have considered)?

**EDIT:**

The Frame Structure is something along the lines of this:

```
Index.html
    menu.html
        banner.html
        list.html
        footer.html
    /lib/index.html
        header.html
        body.html
        footer.html
```

The magic i am referencing is a few hot key shortcuts, find and replace that kind of stuff

Comment: if you explain what this jQuery magic is and how frames are preventing you from doing this, someone might be able to answer your question

Comment: Shard is right - need some more information on this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what you want:

[$.frameReady()](http://ideamill.synaptrixgroup.com/?p=6)

> frameReady lets you run jQuery
>   commands in a target frame as if it
>   were in the local document. It works
>   much like the $(document).ready()
>   function, waiting until the DOM is
>   ready in the target frame before
>   attempting to run your code. It will
>   also load jQuery in the target frame
>   for you if it doesn’t already exist
>   and allows you to load other script
>   files and stylesheets easily.
>   frameReady supports nested frames and
>   iframes in any combination, even
>   dynamically created frames.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the jQuery below to target elements and content in iFrames.

```
$('#iframeId').load(function(){
    $(this.contentDocument).find('#id').html('your text');
});
```